# Why are x and y coordinates located in the top left corner instead of bottom left?

Tags: graphics, awt

`x = 0, y = 0` are located in the top left corner of the screen.
What was the idea implement it this way?

PS: it's bottom left in openGL and it's logical.

Comment: I would argue that it is fairly sensible in that when you're working with coordinates in graphics, you are saying x pixels from here and y pixels from here.  This is especially true if you look at it from a CSS point of view, where things are always defined from the top/left, and not the center of the screen.

Comment: durbnpoisn, fair enough. I don't have much experience with graphics so, it might be sensible but still, openGL system makes more sence for me at this moment.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, @Caleb.  It's a good question.  I sort of equate it to why some languages use 0 as the first index in an array, where others use 1.  Both are sensible for different reasons.  You just have to go with the convention for whatever platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because by java AWT convention the x and y axes are defined differently than in regular algebra. The Y axis goes from the top left, with increasing numbers heading DOWN, unlike the regular co-ordinate plane where increasing y values would be heading UP.

See this link for reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/coordinate.html

Answer (score 1):

For images, like for matrices, the ubiquitous convention is top-down.

In usual drawing, ordinates are counted positively upward because the ground serves as a zero reference.

But when dealing with raster scans, it is much more natural to think in terms of scanning from the top row, like when you write.